Why is there a focus on positive solutions of elliptic eigenvalue problems?
I am looking at the theory of principal eigenvalue problems of elliptic operators. A simple form would be
\begin{align} \label{eu_eqn}
Lu(x) &= \lambda u(x) \quad x \in \Omega \\
u(x) &= 0 \quad x \in \partial\Omega
\end{align}
where $L$ is an elliptic operator and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ a bounded domain. Now we are looking for the smallest eigenvalue of this operator $\lambda_1$.
I understand the math behind it for the most part, what I am missing to understand is why we are looking for positive solutions, where $u_1(x) > 0$, for all $x \in \Omega$. I've looked in a few sources and here on StackExchange, but I haven't found any motivation.

If all eigenfunctions to the smallest eigenvalue are positive (or negative) then the corresponding eigenspace is one-dimensional, i.e., the smallest eigenvalue is simple.
